# How would I modify the definition of the operators "&&" and "||" so that they do not use short circuit evaluation?

Tags: programming-languages, computer-science, semantics

How would I modify the definition of the operators "&&" and "||" so that they do not use short circuit evaluation? Please show the new semantic rule.

I tried the following:
"AND (&&): It returns expression #1 if it can be converted to false - if else it returns expression #2. Therefore, when used with the Boolean value, it returns true if both operands can be converted to true; otherwise, it returns false.
OR (||): it returns expression #1 if it can be converted to true – if-else, it returns expression #2. Therefore, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand can be converted to true - if both can be converted to false, it returns false. "

However, apparently, that's still using short-circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Short-circuit evaluation means that you stop immediately whenever you encounter a value of false for AND and a value of true for OR. This is because the value of the entire expression will always be that no matter what the second term is.

Your AND description is wrong because if expression #1 evaluates to false, expression #2 is not evaluated at all. Same thing with OR.

What you want to do is to evaluate both expressions before manipulating either values.